# Creating an app that references a DLL in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use a DLL in a separate Visual Studio Project, and am using Visual Studio 2015 for this. I am using this tutoral: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx and have successfully created a DLL, now I just need to use it.

Everything is straight forward until I get to step 5) in "Creating an app that uses the DLL": "Choose the drop-down button at the end of the Solution control, and then select Add to Solution from the drop-down list. This adds the new project to the same solution that contains the DLL. Choose the OK button."

There is no "Solution control", I cannot see anything related to what this step is talking about, I have no idea what this means. Please could somebody tell me how to access this dropdown that is supposed to be in the create app window, or alternatively tell me how to use a DLL in the new app some other way?

I have also tried "Add Reference" but when I click that, a box with no option to browse comes up, it just has two sections "Projects" and "Shared Projects" both of which are empty.

Comment: Inside a _Solution Explorer_ (or Solution control) window right click on solution -> *Add..* - *New Project*.

Comment: First node in the Solution Explorer window.  Or just use File > New > Project and it gets added to the solution.

Comment: @Ron thanks, the order of those steps do not make sense to me since it seems to say I am supposed to be in the process of creating the project when right clicking solution explorer which is not possible... but what you said worked